# Error on Node gm Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, streaming

I have the following array of `Buffer` objects that I have created from `base64` encoded image strings consisting of `jpg` and `png` images:

```
[ 
    <Buffer 75 ab 5a 8a 66 a0 7b f8 e9 7a 06 da b1 ee b8 ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 03 02 02 03 02 02 03 03 03 03 ... >,
    <Buffer 75 ab 5a 8a 66 a0 7b f8 e9 7a 06 da b1 ee b8 ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 03 02 02 03 02 02 03 03 03 03 ... >
]
```

I am trying to use the `Node.js` library `gm` to stitch the images together.

```
var currentGm = gm(images.shift());
for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    currentGm.append(images[i]);
}
```

And then `pipe` that data to `res` as a `jpg`.

```
currentGm.stream('jpg').pipe(res);
```

But I am getting this error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn gm ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:478:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:433:17)
```

I am tried checking `err` on the `stream` callback and it is `null`.

Also `currentGm` looks like this:

```
gm {
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _options: {},
  data: {},
  _in: [],
  _out: [],
  _outputFormat: null,
  _subCommand: 'convert',
  sourceBuffer: <Buffer 75 ab 5a 8a 66 a0 7b f8 e9 7a 06 da b1 ee b8 ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 03 02 02 03 02 02 03 03 03 03 ... >,
  source: 'unknown.jpg',
  _sourceFormatters: [ [Function] ] }
```

And `stdout` object from callback looks like this:

```
Socket {
  _connecting: false,
  _hadError: false,
  _handle:
   Pipe {
     _externalStream: {},
     fd: 27,
     writeQueueSize: 0,
     owner: [Circular],
     onread: [Function: onread],
     reading: true },
  _parent: null,
  _host: null,
  _readableState:
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: true,
     sync: false,
     needReadable: true,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events:
   { end: { [Function: g] listener: [Function: onend] },
     finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
     _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
     close: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState:
   WritableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     needDrain: false,
     ending: false,
     ended: false,
     finished: false,
     decodeStrings: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     length: 0,
     writing: false,
     corked: 0,
     sync: true,
     bufferProcessing: false,
     onwrite: [Function],
     writecb: null,
     writelen: 0,
     bufferedRequest: null,
     lastBufferedRequest: null,
     pendingcb: 0,
     prefinished: false,
     errorEmitted: false },
  writable: false,
  allowHalfOpen: false,
  destroyed: false,
  bytesRead: 0,
  _bytesDispatched: 0,
  _sockname: null,
  _writev: null,
  _pendingData: null,
  _pendingEncoding: '' }
```

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X, installing `imagemagick` with `brew` fixed the issue.

`brew install imagemagick`

and in my `router`:

`var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });`